# Inconsistent Application Defined or Object Defined Error 1004 in Excel VBA with .End(x1Up) .row range declaration

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I'm trying to make my ranges flexible. I wrote the following code to make the TCSiteReport range end at the last filled cell in column B of tab "TC Site Report".

```
Dim siteTC As Range
Dim TCSiteReport As Range
Dim lrowTC As Long
lrowTC = Worksheets("TC Site Report").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set TCSiteReport = Worksheets("TC Site Report").Range("B2:B" & lrowTC)
```

This code worked, but when I tried repeating the process with another range in the active sheet, "Quickbooks", I get an "object defined error" or 1004 error, and I'm not sure why as the lines seem to be identical. This is the code that is throwing the error. It's the "LrowIQ = etc." line.

```
Dim itemdescrip As Range
Dim itemQuickDescrip As Range
Dim LrowIQ As Long
LrowIQ = Worksheets("Quickbooks").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).row
Set itemQuickDescrip = Worksheets("Quickbooks").Range("I2:I" & LrowIQ)
```

What do you think is causing this error to be thrown and how should I resolve it?

Comment: it is `xlup` not `x1up`.  Lower Case `L` not the number one.

Comment: You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to flag undeclared variables.

Comment: @BigBen where in the module should I place it? I put it directly above the variable declarations and I'm getting an "Invalid Inside Procedure" error...

Comment: At the very very top of the module. See the linked thread.

Comment: I moved it to be above the sub. I now get a message that says that the 'x1Up' variable is not defined...

Comment: However when I try to define x1Up with Const x1Up As Long = -4162 I get a 'duplicate declaration within scope' error which doesn't make sense if the variable isn't defined before...?

Comment: Ok now I don't get the error anymore...not sure why. Thank you!